# how to Move file from local to sftp folder in Laraver with filesystem?

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems, sftp, move

i want to move file from my local to another server using sftp, here is my sftp setting in config/filesystem.php

```
'sftp' => [
        'driver' => 'sftp',
        'host' => '192.xxx.0.xxx',
        'port' => 22,
        'username' => 'xxx',
        'password' => 'xxx',
        'root' => '/',
        'timeout' => 10,
    ],
```

and here is my code in controller

```
 $file_local = public_path().'/documents/1.pdf';
 $file_sftp = Storage::disk('sftp')->put('1.pdf', $file_local);
 $move = File::move($file_local, $file_ftp);
```

i got this error
[image]

but in the sftp folder, the file is exist but  corrupted, please need your help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

777 permission! is the key entrance for evilness! I ldn't configure my apps that way! I would check first if the file still exists in the storage folder ( the file you are renaming ). My second assumption - the file is owned by a completely different user? Normally the entire project should be under one user.group owner! It might be apache.groupName in your case but you should double check. So I would do

```
ls -la  // in project root directory and grab the ownerUser and ownerGroup names 
// then I ld make sure everything is owned by them - back up your project first before changing ownership!
sudo chown  -R ownerUser.ownerGroup *   // -R for recursive
```

If not, I would save it else where other than the storage folder. Hope this help you